# Probability to measure certain energies

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

How can I calculate the probability that the measured energy is equal to some given energy? I find it hard to solve question b of the following example. [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating the probability of a given energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186469)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule), the probability of measuring an energy $E_i$ (meaning the system is in state $\psi_i$) is given by $|\psi_i \cdot \psi(x,t)|^2$. Since energy eigenstates are orthogonal, $\psi_i \cdot \psi_j = \delta_{ij}$. Since you want the probability that the system measures $E_2$ for the energy, you want the probability that the wavefunction is $\psi_2$, so you can calculate $\psi_2 \cdot \psi(x,t)$ and take the magnitude squared.

Comment: After conducting research, I found online that the probability of measuring an energy $E_i$ is given by $\mid{c_i}\mid^2$. Is it equivalent to $|\psi_i \cdot \psi(x,t)|^2$?

Comment: If you read my answer then you should be able to answer that yourself. If there is something unclear about my answer then say so.

Comment: Ok, I showed they are equivalent using orthogonality and basic algebra, but it wasn't trivial for me.