# I need to find the probability of measuring certain energies with the given linear combination wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

I have a group of wavefunctions given by $\psi_{n}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{\sqrt{2 / a} \sin (n \pi x / a),} & {0 \leq x \leq a} \\ {0,} & {\text { otherwise }}\end{array}\right.$

I also have $\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \psi_{1}(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \psi_{2}(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \psi_{3}(x)$

Now I need to find the values of the energies that can be obtained and with what probabilities. I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186469/calculating-the-probability-of-a-given-energy) answer so I understand that the probability of each energy is given by $P\left(E_{0}\right)=\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi^{*} \psi \mathrm{d} x\right|^{2}$ where $\Phi$ is an energy eigenstate but I am unsure if each of the group of wavefunctions that I have are eigenstates. Don't the eigenstates need to be solutions to the time independent SE for the same value of E? If they are not energy eigenstates how would I solve this without being given a value of E?

Comment: First you have to know what the energy operator is! Once you know that, apply it to your wavefunctions to determine their energies.

Comment: *Don't the eigenstates need to be solutions to the time independent SE for the same value of E?* No. In general energy eigenstates can and will have *different* energies. If two or more of them happen to have the *same* energy, this is called degeneracy.

Comment: So if I apply the Hamiltonian to each $\psi_n$, I know what energy values can be obtained (they do have associated energy eigenvalues). But can I then use the information given in the linked post to say that the probabilities are simply the coefficients of each $\psi_n$ in  $\Psi$?

Comment: The probabilities are the *squares of the complex magnitudes* of the coefficients, but you need to understand how that follows from the integral you wrote.

Comment: BTW, don’t be surprised if this gets closed as a homework-like question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the wavefunction at $t \ = \ 0$ as:

$$\Psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \psi_{1}(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \psi_{2}(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \psi_{3}(x)$$

Since this is a linear combination of stationary states, the probabilities of measuring different energies don't change with time, even when I introduce time-dependence, and they are equal to the squared coefficients of each of the position-space energy eigenstates in the expansion of $\Psi(x, \ 0)$. Thus, we will measure $E_1$ with probability $1/2$, $E_2$ with probability $1/3$, and $E_3$ with probability $1/6$.

Now, let's look at this in general. In order to find the probability of measuring any of the allowed energies $E_n$ corresponding to the time-independent wavefunction $\psi_n$ in the following expansion:

$$\Psi(x, \ 0) \ = \ \displaystyle\sum_{n} c_n \psi_n(x)$$

we essentially have to "project" this wavefunction onto the stationary state that corresponds to the energy we are trying to find the probability of measuring. It follows that we take the inner product of $\psi_a$ and $\Psi$ to get the probability that we will measure $E_a$. Since all of the wavefunctions are orthogonal, the inner product between $\psi_m$ and $\psi_n$ with $n \ \neq \ m$ will just be $0$, thus this inner product will "pick out" the coefficient on the $\psi_a$ term, giving us the coefficient $c_a$, which we then modulus square to get the probability:

$$P(E_a) \ = \ \Big| \displaystyle\int \ \psi_a^* \ \Psi(x, \ t) \ \text{d} x \Big|^2 \ = \ \Big| c_a \ \displaystyle\int \psi_a^* \psi_a \ \text{d}x \Big|^2 \ = \ |c_a|^2$$