# Generally, Probability of given level. Particularly, Particle in a box probability of a given level 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, probability

I had the horrifying realization that I don't fully understand how to find probability of a state with a given energy. Referring to this post ([Calculating the probability of a given energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186469/)) and Shankar page 146, I think I have an idea of what I am trying to do. The coefficients of interest should be (Shankar notation)
$$
a_E=\langle{E_n|\psi}\rangle
$$
However, If I find $\psi$ from the Hamiltonian (and let's assume $\psi$ is orthonormal), isn't this just $|\psi_n|^2$. This doesn't make much sense.

Specific Questions:

1. Is the approach outlined correct?

If so,

2. Is the coeff then just the inverse of the normalization coff of a given state $\psi_n$? As taking $\psi $ to include normalization coeff wouldn't make much sense. All $a_E$ would be 1.
3. In case of infinite square well, I believe that the modulus squared is the same for all $\psi_n$. If this is the true based on the above, the probability density function would be uniform over $n$, and, therefore, the probability of a given energy would be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry it's not that horrifying. Actually it's a nice opportunity to improve your knowledge :)

> However, If I find $\psi$ from the Hamiltonian (and let's assume $\psi$ is orthonormal), isn't this just $|\psi_n|^2$. This doesn't make much sense.

Yes, in that case you just get $|\langle \psi_n |\psi_n \rangle |^2 $ which is just $1$ because the state is normalized. In other words, if the particle is already in the specific energy eigenstate $\psi_n$, then there is 100% chance of measuring that energy $E_n$. But if the state were, for example, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_1 \rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\psi_n\rangle $ then there would be only a 50% probability.

Specific Questions:

> 1. Is the approach outlined correct?

Yes, although your current expression is missing a $| \cdot |^2$. It should be $|\langle E_n|\psi \rangle|^2$. Otherwise it could be a complex number and definitely not a probability!

Also, if there are multiple eigenstates of that energy (let's call them $E_{n1}, E_{n2}, ...$) then the probability of getting that energy is the total probability of getting any one of those states:

$$|\langle E_{n1}|\psi \rangle|^2 + |\langle E_{n2}|\psi \rangle| + ...$$

> 2. Is the coeff then just the inverse of the normalization coff of a given state $\psi_n$?As taking $\psi $ to include normalization coeff wouldn't make much sense. All $a_E$ would be 1.

Nope it's not. If $|\psi \rangle $ is already in energy eigenstate $n$, then the inner product with state $|E_n \rangle$ is 1, and with all other energy eigenstates is 0. But most states are not energy eigenstates, because the general solution is a sum of all energy eigenstates with arbitrary coefficients. So the inner product with psi squared can be any number from 0 to 1.

> 3. In case of infinite square well, I believe that the modulus squared is the same for all $\psi_n$. If this is the true based on the above, the probability density function would be uniform over n, and, therefore, the probability of a given energy would be zero.

See the answers to (1) and (2), if you are still confused about (3) then feel free to follow up with another question in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think this Shankar question confused me, but that just shows my understanding was shaky to begin with. (1 step back, 2 steps forward). I am glad I was correct in my approach, Q1, (I was considering $|A_N|^2$ as the probability as Griffiths does and Shankar does inconsistently (should have clarified)). (Q1.1) In the second paragraph of your response to Q1, you are referring to degen E levels?

Comment: (Q2 follow up) Your responds to Q2 was enlightening. You are saying most states in the real world (ie not the textbook world of like 4 idealized potentials lol) a particle will be in linear combination of states, correct? Two follow up questions: (Q2.1) In the world of quantum class where states are contrived this linear combination will generally be given or will be like measured something what are probabilities of measuring this value of this other observable (which could be E)? (Q2.2) In "the real world" how would one determine this linear combination of states? By reverse of this process?

Comment: Using the inner product (magnitude squared) is always correct for the probability of getting some outcome. But if your state is expanded in terms of eigenstates of the energy already, with coefficients $A_N$, then yes this becomes equal to $|A_N|^2$. 

Yes in the second paragraph I am referring to degenerate E levels.

Comment: Yes, almost always a state will be in a sum of different energy states. But not always, and we can prepare states that are not in a sum (superposition) of different energies in a lab. So I wouldn't say it's an idealization, but it's also a very common scenario to have superpositions. 

(Q2.1) In a class, you would usually be given the state in a linear combination. The only way to find it that way if it wasn't given that way, is if you were also asked to solve for $\psi(t)$ given $\psi(0$, and if $\psi(0)$ is not in superposition of different energies. From there you can find probabilities.

Comment: (Q2.2) There are a few ways. Method 1: You could prepare an energy eigenstate first, change the hamiltonian by putting the particle in a different, known potential and then let it evolve (if you keep the same H then it will stay the same) and calculate the future state by Schrödinger's equation. Method 2: Just because something is in superposition in energy, doesn't mean it's in superposition in other variables. You could in principle do a measurement of another variable that leaves the particle in a superposition state in energy.